# database and ER diagram for this scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

A company serves many clients through selling different products. These products are sold by sales persons who then take 0.1% out of every deal they make. Sales persons are not paid monthly salary but are on basic pay, i.e, 1200 + commission in sales. There are total 12 employees , 10 sales persons and 2 managers. Each manager has 5 sales persons working under him. The company requires the following information:

1. each sales record made by sales person with date
2. sales person total income every month
3. bonus to those sales persons who make sale more than 1 million rupees  in any year
4. no. of sales persons having gmail account

Comment: This sound like homework... what have you done so far ?

Comment: Honestly, i don't even know how to start. i'm new to database and this thing is far beyond my level of understanding

Comment: Oooo very good .. you know problem statement then.... why are you waiting here ?  
please go ahead and implement it .... We will help if you face any issues...

Comment: The main problem i'm struggling with is to calculate the salary of the sales person. I've got products cost in the products table and how many products a sales person sold in the sales-record table. But this salary column is in salesperson table. How can  i calculate salary by using data from two different tables?

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem i'm struggling with is to calculate the salary of the
>   sales person. I've got products cost in the products table and how
>   many products a sales person sold in the sales-record table. But this
>   salary column is in salesperson table. How can i calculate salary by
>   using data from two different tables?

If you can calculate the dynamic % and the static salary, then all you have to do is to use **`UNION ALL`**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26882/5)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT sum(t.salary) annual_salary
    FROM 
        (
            -- the select for the dynamic part
            select (15500000*0.001) AS salary -- FROM table 
            union all
            -- the select for the static one
            select 30000 AS salary -- FROM table
        ) AS t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26882/5/0)**:

```
| annual_salary |
|---------------|
|         45500 |
```